# Is every locally compact connected homogeneous metric space a manifold cross a continuum?

Tags: gn.general-topology, mg.metric-geometry, continuum-theory

Suppose that $(X,d)$ is a locally compact connected homogeneous metric space, where by homogeneous I mean that for any $x_0,x_1 \in X$ there exists an isometry $f:X\rightarrow X$ such that $f(x_0)=x_1$. Does there necessarily exist a connected  manifold $M$ and a continuum (compact connected metric space) $K$ such that $X$ and $M\times K$ (with the max metric) are bi-uniformly equivalent, i.e. there exists a bijection $g:M\times K \rightarrow X$ such that $g$ and $g^{-1}$ are both uniformly continuous. If so can $M$ and $K$ be taken to be homogeneous themselves?

When I looked for an answer to this question the only thing I could find was [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.7893) paper of Berestovskii, which, if I'm understanding it correctly, gives a positive answer with the additional assumption that the space has a geodesic metric.

Comment: What about (pseudo-arc)$\times$(pseudo-arc minus a point)? Or (pseudo-arc)$^2$ minus a point? Probably not the product of a continuum and a manifold.  But are they homogeneous? My intuition is that the second example is, because (circle)$^2$ minus a point is  homeomorphic to $\mathbb R^2$. Maybe an easier example to consider is (solenoid)$^2$ minus a point.

Comment: It seems that you locally compact homogeneous space $(X,d)$ is uniformly homeomorphic to the homogeneous space $G/H$ of some locally compact group $G$ by a closed subgroup $H$. Being locally compact (and maybe something else like $\sigma$-compact), the group $G$ contains a compact normal subgroup $K$ such that $G/K$ is a Lie group, so a manifold. Then $HK$ is a closed subgroup in $G$ and $G/HK$ seems to be a manifold. Therefore, $(X,d)$ admits a perfect map onto a manifold $M$, whose fiber is homeomorphic to the compact homogeneous space $HK/H$.

Comment: This is continuation of my comment. Now it remains to prove (or disprove) that the fibration $G/H\to G/KH$ is trivial.

Comment: By the way, what happens at the level of locally compact abelian groups? In this case the Pontryagin duality theory can give some counterexamples.

Comment: And what about locally compact topological groups? Is it true that any locally compact topological group decomposes into the product of a Lie group and a compact group?

Comment: @D.S.Lipham I don't think a topologically homogeneous metric space can always be given a homogeneous metric, can it? For instance the Hilbert cube is topologically homogeneous but I doubt it has a homogeneous metric.

Comment: @TarasBanakh I know that locally compact connected Abelian groups are always $\mathbb{R}^n \times K$ for some compact group $K$. This is discussed in [this](https://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2008/11/locally_compact_hausdorff_abel.html) blog post. I don't know what happens in the non-Abelian case.

Comment: @JamesHanson You are right: not every topologically homogeneous space (form example the Hilbert cube) can be endowed with a homogenous metric. It is known that locally contractible locally compact homogeneous metric spaces are  finite-dimensional manifolds.

Comment: @TarasBanakh Do you have a source for that?

Comment: @JamesHanson Yes, see https://www.degruyter.com/view/j/forum.2015.27.issue-4/forum-2013-0033/forum-2013-0033.xml Also the same result was independently proved by Hoffman: https://ivv5hpp.uni-muenster.de/u/lkram_01/publ/39.pdf